# How to process a series of files with elisp?

Tags: text, emacs, elisp

I'm a newbie to programming, so please bear with me here...

I have a directory full of files called "foo01.txt", "foo02.txt", etc. and a function called `MyFunction`. I want to open each file as a buffer, run `MyFunction` on it, write the buffer to its file, kill the buffer and move on to the next file in the series until all the files are done.

I think all the pieces I need to do this are described in the Cookbook (http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook) but I'm not really understanding how to put it all together. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Answer

If you're looking for an answer in pure elisp, you could do something like this:

```
(defun process-file (f)
  (save-excursion 
    (find-file f)
    (my-function)     ; Call your function here.
    (write-file f)
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))

(defun process-files (dir) 
  (mapc 'process-file
        (directory-files dir t ".txt$")))
```

`process-files` will iterate over each file in a given directory and apply `process-file` to all .txt files. You can call it like so:

```
(process-files "~/target-directory")
```

You can copy this into a *scratch* buffer and play around with the individual parts. The most interesting functions are:

- `mapc` - applies a function to each item in a list
- `directory-files` - gets all files and folders in a directory, in this case retrieving all .txt files
- `find-file` - opens a file in a buffer (this is what is run when you type `C-x C-f`)

---

## Learning Lisp

If you're learning Lisp for its own sake, I can recommend [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). You'll be able to work through a surprising amount of the book using Elisp. Otherwise, download a Common Lisp environment like [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/).

Answer (score 4):

The good in Emacs is that there are often many ways to solve a given problem, thanks to Emacs openness.

For instance, you could learn an easy trick in Emacs, that will help you now and in the future:

Here is a *dired* listing, eg from <kbd>C-x f</kbd>`/home/me/mydir/`

```
  /home/me/mydir:
  total used in directory 32 available 5575136
  drwxr-xr-x  10 me  brainers   340 Jan 18 15:50 .
  drwxr-xr-x  78 me  brainers  2652 Feb  2 18:08 ..
  -rw-r--r--   4 me  brainers   136 Apr  1  2012 a.txt
  -rw-r--r--  16 me  brainers   544 Feb  1 09:56 b.txt
  -rw-r--r--   6 me  brainers   204 Apr  6  2012 c.txt
```

go to the first one (using <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> keys), ie `a.txt`, and do

- <kbd>C-x (</kbd> to start a macro recording
- <kbd>f</kbd> to open that file
- <kbd>M-x myfunction</kbd> to run that *myfunction* function
- <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to save the file
- <kbd>C-x k</kbd> to close that file, back to *dired*
- <kbd>down</kbd> key to go to next file (`b.txt` in this case)
- <kbd>C-x )</kbd> to end the macro

then for each file (from `b.txt`), do

- <kbd>C-x e</kbd> to execute the macro, it will do the same with `b.txt`, and then point to `c.txt`. (You could just do `e` to re-execute the macro if you don't do anything in between two macro executions)

Be careful not to run the macro on something that you don't want to be processed.

*Notes:*

- if you make any mistake during the creation of the macro, Emacs will interrupt the recording process (thus, <kbd>C-x )</kbd> will complain there is no macro being recorded). In this case the macro has to be started again from <kbd>C-x (</kbd>.
- <kbd>C-key</kbd> is *Control key*, <kbd>M-key</kbd> is *Meta key* usually <kbd>Alt-key</kbd>. And <kbd>C-x k</kbd> means *Control x then k key*.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this. I'd like to get the hang of using Lisp, but this will probably be easier a much easier approach for me as an immediate solution.