# Is there a way to read a few lines from the head of a file in emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs

I know  the `head` command of shell. However, sometimes it's not convenient to open a shell in emacs and execute `head` command in that shell. Is there `built-in` command in emacs for this?

Comment: Can't you do a *Esc* `! head file.txt` ? Otherwise, write the appropriate Elisp code...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I see.. I forgot I can use `!`

Comment: You can also [make a macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670371/how-to-process-a-series-of-files-with-elisp/14670495#14670495) to repeat the process easily.